# Explicitly Mentioning a index table space for index created behind the scene by a unique constraint

Tags: oracle, indexing, unique-constraint, tablespace

I am fairly new to the oracle database world so i'm a little confused with the requirement here that I have for one of the bootcamps that I am supposed to complete at the new work place.

First requirement is I need to create an unique constraint UNIQ_BEL_CLIENT_EMP on client_id and client_nbr.

which I did as

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQ_BEL_CLIENT_EMP UNIQUE(client_id,client_nbr)
```

Then it also says that the unique constraint will automatically create a unique index behind the scenes so specify PDC_IX for the index tablespace.

I understand we can specify index table space for the given column/ columns which we create explicitly, but how can we specify a index table space for something created behind the scenes? I will be highly obliged if someone could help me answer this question.

OR is it valid to do something like this if the unique index is created behind the scenes for unique constraint????

```
CONSTRAINT UNIQ_BEL_CLIENT_EMP UNIQUE(client_id, client_nbr) USING INDEX TABLESPACE PDC_IX
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create the index you want inline with the constraint and specify the tablespace there.  E.g.,

```
CREATE TABLE matt1 ( a number, 
                     CONSTRAINT matt1_u1 UNIQUE (a) 
                        USING INDEX ( CREATE INDEX matt1_u1_idx ON matt1 (a) TABLESPACE USERS ) );
```